# Creating a new tibble with hundreds of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I want to create a `tibble` using functions from the tidyverse with hundreds of columns, and I don't want to type them out column-by-column.

Is it possible to create a `tibble` with column names **using the `tibble()` function**? (Note, I like how `tibble()` creates columns sequentially, so wrapping base R solutions in `tibble()` likely won't be satisfying).

For a more concrete working example, let the solution be a call to `tibble()` creating a 5-column `tbl` with 10 randomly sampled integers between 1 and 10 (`sample(10)`) in column 1 and each subsequent column calculated by the previous column + `sample(10)`. For example, the following code but ***not*** using `"col2=..."` to create each column:

```r
set.seed(1)
tibble(col1 = sample(10),
       col2 = col1 + sample(10),
       col3 = col2 + sample(10),
       col4 = col3 + sample(10),
       col5 = col4 + sample(10))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     9    12    17    18    22
 2     4     5    14    18    27
 3     7    12    13    16    23
 4     1     9    15    21    27
 5     2     4    14    16    17
 6     5    11    18    25    35
 7     3    13    15    20    28
 8    10    19    23    31    34
 9     6    10    13    22    24
10     8    15    23    33    38
```

**Edit**

Okay, apparently this might be impossible with `tibble()` alone (TBD). Is it possible to create a `tbl` using the `tibble()` function with 100 columns each named `col1`, `col2`, ... `col100`? I don't care what's inside!

Comment: Sounds like a `Reduce` operation in base R, though that is not staying in the tibble world, it does give the same values: - `set.seed(1); Reduce(\`+\`, replicate(5,list(sample(10))), accumulate=TRUE)`

Comment: Or if you are more familiar with *purrr* from the tidyverse, then `accumulate(rerun(5, sample(10)), \`+\`)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if you are going to like this solution but here is one way using a `for` loop

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

set.seed(1)
df <- tibble::tibble(col1 = sample(10))
n <- 10

for (i in seq_len(n)[-1])  {
   df <- df %>% mutate(!!paste0("col",i) := !!sym(paste0("col", i-1)) + sample(10))
}


df
# A tibble: 10 x 10
#    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9 col10
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     9    12    17    18    22    32    38    42    48    54
# 2     4     5    14    18    27    34    35    43    44    46
# 3     7    12    13    16    23    26    29    30    35    44
# 4     1     9    15    21    27    29    37    46    54    57
# 5     2     4    14    16    17    23    33    39    49    59
# 6     5    11    18    25    35    44    48    58    67    75
# 7     3    13    15    20    28    29    31    34    41    45
# 8    10    19    23    31    34    39    46    53    56    63
# 9     6    10    13    22    24    32    41    46    50    51
#10     8    15    23    33    38    42    47    49    51    56
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Holding out for an easier solution but will give it to you if nothing else pops up! (Also, see my recent edit)

Comment: @Brigadeiro I am not sure if `tibble` can be treated differently in this case. As far as your new edit is concerned maybe you could do `n = 10; 
as_tibble(matrix(sample(100), ncol = 10, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("col", seq_len(n)))))
`